# SSL Certificate conversion beetween PEM and DER formats

Tags: ssl, openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I am trying to create a self-signed certificate using my own CA. 
All of the certificates and keys are currently in PEM-Format. In order to have the certificate accepted from my Android-phone I need to create a `CA.crt`-File in binary DER-Format.

I did create this file using openssl with

```
openssl x509 -in CA-cert.pem -inform PEM -outform DER > CA.crt
```

However, after installing `CA.crt` on my Android, a website´s certificate (`www.example.com-cert.pem`) signed with `CA-cert.pem` still shows as invalid in Chrome for Android. The cerificates are (at least as far as I understand it) created correctly and show no difference when converting back:

```
diff -u CA-cert.pem <(openssl x509 -in CA.crt -inform DER -outform PEM)
```

What am i missing here? Do I need to create another Version of the website´s certificate (e.g. `www.example.com.crt`) in DER-Format?

*EDIT:* don't know if this should work in the first place, but trying to validate the certificate against `CA.crt` fails with an error:

```
$ openssl verify -CAfile CA.crt www.example.com-cert.pem
Error loading file CA.crt
```

the same works well with the PEM-Version:

```
$ openssl verify -CAfile CA-cert.pem www.example.com-cert.pem
www.example.com-cert.pem: OK
```

Comment: It is looking fine. Instead of redirecting the output, you can try -out <filename> option. There can be multiple reasons for this to be invalid.

Comment: @dbasic also tried it that way, doesn't make any difference (the files generated are completely identical)

Comment: Please check if self signed certificates are allowed. Because it could be chain verification that fails and says that the certificate is invalid.

Comment: I did import the CA.crt as a root-certificate on my Android device, which i already had working with other certificates.

Comment: Don't know why you're getting the error, I just know that `$ openssl verify -CAfile CA.crt www.example.com-cert.pem` fails because OpenSSL expect PEM formated chain. Try putting `-inform DER`. I'm sure the problem is not with your DER encoding...

Comment: unfortunately, verify doesn't accept the `-inform` parameter.

Comment: From the openssl verify [documentation](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/verify.html) regarding the -CAfile argument:  "The file should contain multiple certificates in PEM format concatenated together."  There is no option for DER certificates.

Comment: Can you provide the specific "invalid" error you are seeing?  Certificates can be invalid for a number of reasons (server name doesn't match, certificate is expired, trust/chain issues, etc.